# On OnepageController.php how I can check checkout method is checkout as guest

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, onepage-checkout

I want to check checkout method of user on OnepageController.php

eg if checkout as guest then value will be guest

I tried the following:

```
$this->getRequest()->getPost('method')
```

...but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getCheckoutMethod()
```